# The task failed to activate HighVersionLie

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing the UWP application with VS 2019. I wanted to update my UWP apps and the app certification kit has kept getting the following error since Windows Update 20H2: "Error when activating HighVersionLie by the task"

The apps are written in c# and I would need an example of how to fix this if possible. Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the local WACK tool? If it is, you could try to upload your package to the store directly, There will be an online WACK test when your app is submitted. We will take that result as standard.

Comment: Yes, I use the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK) tool supplied with VS 2019

Comment: So you could try to upload your package to the store directly and wait for the result of the online WACK test.

Comment: I have the same issue with 20H2

Comment: Have the same issue, but the Store now also rejects the package.